# Spring Boot Menu Component Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm wondering how I can create a menu that is loaded dynamically (from the db) on every page.

I use spring boot + thymeleaf. no XML, just spring annotations.

I tried adding a controller with a method that returns a category object (which is used in the menu) annotated with (@ModelAttribute) but I couldn't use that attribute in my HTML pages.
Here is my header:

```
<ul>
<li th:each="category : ${categories}" th:text="${category.name}">
</ul>
```

Now, this "ul" is loaded in every page since it's on the menu bar. I don't want to add the following code in every controller:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
mav.addObject("categories", getCategories());
```

I need a way to achieve this without adding this code on every controller. just once.

Thanks

Comment: You can return a map to thymeleaf where in map holds the category object. If you could post the code you have written it would be helpful

Comment: I almost have no code yet, since I tried and failed many times. Maybe this  edit explains the idea better.

Comment: Try this `public String myMethod(Map<String, Object> model) {
  mode.put("categories",getCategories());
  return "index";
 }`. Then iterate through `categories` object in thymeleaf and it should work. If your controller is returning string you can just call the thymeleaf template name in the return statement like `return "index";`

Comment: The problem is that this method shouldn't return "index", it's on every page and every template. it shouldn't return a page at all. but only a list of categories that can be used on any thymeleaf template on the site.

Comment: Okay. You can do that but in thymeleaf itself by including the page as we do it in jsps and free marker.

Comment: Would you please explain how it can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice`, adding "categories" attribute for each controller response. Since it's a spring component, you can autowire any of your existing services in it to retrieve categories.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CategoriesAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categories", getCategories());
    }
}
```

See my github project with complete solution: [project](https://github.com/IlyaZinkovich/spring-boot-menu-controller-solution)

Comment: Thanks man, this worked! :)

but I'm just curious, can I have specific attributes that are only added when a specific component (page, fragment, div ... etc) is loaded in the page?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible since view resolving happens only after you load all attributes to your model. You need to use AJAX for this kind of purpose, fetching only needed data separately.